# Vendors and contract employees

Tags: work-experience

I have a terrible situation where I forced myself into, I was a college fresher and I joined into a reputed company immediately after college as vendor.

So my immediate permanent employee and me are doing very great for all these three years. We had  a very close bonding, we share so  many things too in person and all is going well. Some of my employees are going for a film and I asked my immediate permanent employee for permission, he said no. I felt very bad that whole day. The next day during our casual talks I came and asked him what was the reason he said no. The matter went slowly increasing in tone and finally out of my close bonding with him, I pointed out that you permanent employees go often and we don't get to go like this parties so often. I even assured you, that I will come back and do work, why didn't you allow me to go. He clearly told me that I am a vendor and I have work now and I can't go.

I felt very offended by these words and I cant talk properly with him now and my work can go forward if this happens and I cant suddenly work to a person like that knowing know..

Any pointers and stop gaps are where to stop relationships in office?

Comment: Seeing you are in India I cannot say for sure but in the US there is a clear distinction between contractor and employee.  Several companies have been sued for calling people a contractor but the person actually qualified as an employee due to regulations.  Because of this contractors are treated differently than employees when it comes to parties and such.  You would need to look at the local regulations but I would not be surprised if there was something similar.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, contractors and permanent employees are generally treated differently. I've worked in a place where they got all the same perks (Christmas parties, social functions and such), but that is rare. Where I currently am (a place with thousands of employees), permanent employees egt a bunch of perks that contractors don't:

- permanent employees get social functions
- permanent employees get training
- permanent employees get career growth and management positions
- permanent employees get free lunches
- permanent employees get subsidized parking
- permanent employees get lockers and access to the gym

There is nothing wrong with this, the firm simply takes the view that I am the employee of the consultancy that I work for, not them.

These are often company policies, in which case your boss in simply implementing the rules. It does not mean you need to change your relationships between yourself and him or the other staff.

Comment: In addition to the benefits employees get, in general they make less than a contractor doing their same job.  If you are a contractor, figure in all the perks when negotiating your rate so you can provide them for your self.

Answer (score 0):

> i pointed out that you permanent employees go often and we dont get to go like this parties

Contractors and permanent employees are of course different. Why would you expect the way the manager treats you the same as he treats his own permanent employees?

> Any pointers and stop gaps are where to stop relationships in office?

You have at least two options:

- Join them i.e. become a permanent employee so that you receive equal treatments.

or

- Leave them, i.e. find another job and then quit this one.

The spirit of this answer is that you can't have everything, i.e. being a contractor and then expect to be treated as a permanent employee at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**Take it this way:** You are at home with your family, and you have called in a plumber to fix your toilet who is paid by the hour. You and your family are about to watch a movie, and plumber insists on  watching the movie with you while you are paying him.

Your reaction?